# Async pixel transfers not supported

Tags: java, android

I created a webview app from streaming but without audio support.

Minimal example code:

```
mWebViewClient = new myWebViewClient();
webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);

WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
settings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
settings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

webView.setSoundEffectsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
webView.loadUrl("bemusic.vebto.com/");
```

I'm getting this error:

> I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async
>   pixel transfers not supported
>
> debug eror android studio

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: how create app webview to this url bemusic.vebto.com

Comment: im tri create but song not play

Comment: im use android studio